# In JMP, how to custom graph line by specifying the curve name?

Tags: customization, sas-jmp, jsl

In JMP, we can custom any fit curve using this code

```
obj << (Curve[1] << Line Style( DashDot ));
```

Now what I want to customize the line style not based from curve number but by curve name.

Example, if I have 5 curves (grouped by day of the week), I want all days that start with "S" (i.e. weekends) to be DashDot.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It consists of two steps:
1. Store the grouping column contents in a list. Get the size of the list
2. Add a for loop in the plotting script which customs the line style if a certain criteria is fulfilled.

Here's the code for step1:

```
Summarize(A = by(groupcol));
B=groupcol<<get property(value ordering);
If (Isempty(B),
GroupList=A;,
GroupList=B;
);
GroupListN=Nitems(GroupList);
```

Here's the code for step2:

```
For( c=1, c<=GroupListN, c++,
    If (Left(GroupList[c],1)=="S",
    plotscript=plotscript||"biv << (Curve[" ||Char(c)||"] << Line Style( Dashed ));";
        );
    );
plotscript  = plotscript|| "rbiv = biv<<report;"
plotscript = Eval( Parse( plotscript ) );
```

The plotscript variable contains the plotting script. The second code block is added.